# how to merge two array into single histogram in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to compare two histogram.
In array A and B there are 50 values.
I want to show them in to one histogram using different color for A and B plot in matlab.

This is my current code:

```
load iris.txt;
A=iris(:,1);
B=iris(:,2);
```

Can anyone help me to do that?

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow. Please share some code so we can help you!

Comment: load iris.txt;
A=iris(:,1);
B=iris(:,2);
now I want to show both A and B values in one histogram with different colors.

Comment: please update your question with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put all your data in a matrix

for example:

```
figure
rng(0,'twister') 
data = randn(1000,3);
hist(data)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply But I got the ans By
Hist(A)
hold on
Hist(B)
Hold off